# CustomUserManager is not called when creating new user from admin

Tags: django, django-models

My problem is that I have created a CustomUserManager, and override the create_user and create_superuser functions.
The problem is that any of those functions are not called when I create a new user from admin page.

If I create a superuser from console, with the command
 `python manage.py createsuperuser` the function create_superuser from my CustomUserManager is called.

I have created a CustomUser that inherits from AbstractUser.
Alose I have created a CustomUserManager that inherits from BaseUserManager.

This is the CustomUserManager class

```py
# managers.py
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        # Stuff

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        # Stuff
```

This is the CustomUser, that sets object to CustomUserManager

```py
# models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Also I have two forms for my CustomUser, to edit or create a new user.

```py
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)
```

Finally I have created a CustomUserAdmin class where I set the add_form, form and the model with which to work.

```py
# admin.py
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    change_password_form = AdminPasswordChangeForm
    # stuff
```

Comment: Did you register your model admin?

Comment: Yes, on admin.py after define my CustomUserAdmin, 
```python
admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```